# Expanding circles causing mobile screen to resize

Tags: jquery, css

I have circles appearing at random places on the viewport and expanding till they fill up the entire screen. The animation is perfect on a desktop but causes the screen to resize on mobile and stutter, to accommodate the expanding circles. I want the circles to expand out of the viewport if required.

Link to the animation: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation/

I have tried removing `overflow-x : hidden;` and `overflow-y : hidden;` but this causes the viewport to stutter.

Any help is most appreciated.

Jquery:

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        function makeDiv(colorChoice){
            var divsize = 1000;
            var color = colorChoice;
            $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
                'width':divsize+'px',
                'height':divsize+'px',
                'background-color': color,
                'transform': 'scale(0)'
            });

            var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();
            var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();
            $newdiv.css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'left':posx+'px',
                'top':posy+'px',
                'border-radius':'50%',
                'display':'none'
            }).appendTo( 'body' ).addClass('animate').css({'display':'block'}).one(animationEnd,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        };
        var id = setInterval(function(){makeDiv('black')},3000);
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    padding : 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation: expand 2500s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
    }

    100%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(100.0,100.0);
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add the viewport meta tag (to make the layout responsive) and remove the 1000px width of div.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```